# unwanted entry on saveAll

Tags: sql, cakephp-1.3

I have a table `applications` with a HABTM relationship with another table named `users`. The table linking these 2 together is `applications_users`.

Now, with this code,

```
$data = array(
    'Application' => array(
        'id' => 123
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'application_id' => 123,
        'user_id' => 456
    )
);
$this->Application->saveAll($data);
```

I'm getting the expected lines in my tables, but I'm also getting a strange line in `applications_users` that contains `123` in both `applicaiton_id` and `user_id`.

Any idea where this line does come form ? And how to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake magic put it there!
And it is supposed to as it is, as you said, the link table between applications and users tables.
 The HABTM relationship is a "many-to-many" relationship that need a third table to link records from the two tables.

The key code here is this:

```
'application_id' => 123,
```

that tell cake that the user belongs to the application with the id=123 and also that the user with the id=123 has the application with id (application_id)=123.

If you don't want to link the two, remove the above line.

Comment: OK, great, it works ! Thanks.But I still don't understand why this line tells cake that the user with id 123 exists. The user_id specifically tells cake that the user's id is 456, don't it ?